# Python: Specifying Start and Stop values using range()

Tags: python, range

I've written a program that evaluates whether an input string is a palindrome.  Part of this is a for loop (Code A) that uses the range () function to target string characters in variable 'a' and make a new string, 'b', which is 'a' reversed.  I've got the for loop working fine in Code A, but my initial version (Code B) wasn't successful.  Any ideas why no variable is output for variable 'b' in Code B?  Is it because I'm giving the range() function a stop value it will never reach if it uses the default step value of +1?  Thanks!

Code A - this works :)

```
def Code_A(a):
    b=''
    for i in range (len (a)-1,-1,-1):
        b+=a[i]
    return b

print 'Code A Output: '+ Code_A('abcdefg')
```

Code B - this doesn't work :(

```
def Code_B(a):
    b=''
    for i in range (len (a)-1,-1):
        b+=a[i]
    return b

print 'Code B Output: '+ Code_B('abcdefg')
```

Output

```
Code A Output: gfedcba
Code B Output:
```

Comment: yes, `B` doesn't work because it uses default step `1`

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it doesn't work.

For the case where `stop > start`, a `range` will be empty if `step < 0` and undefined if `step == 0`, since you cannot get from `start` to `stop` by adding a multiple of `step`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check if a string is a palindrome is to check the string against its inverse as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

We  would obtain:

```
is_palindrome('kayak') # True

is_palindrome('city') # False
```

note: it doesn't directly answers the question but offer a neat solution to the palindrome problem